# opening sap and then proceeding to login screen through c# Automation

Tags: c#, .net, user-interface, vbscript, sap-gui

I am trying to open SAP GUI and connect to the SAP system using the following code. I had to remove the earlier post due to some mistakes in post. I want to open SAP Logon 7.30 screen and then proceed to logon screen where I want to login using some credentials.

Login is working now, although I was getting some errors of connection entry point not found in the first code named `opensap`, but still I can't make the SapBOX screen automatically process to the login screen.

Please help in the code. Any help will be highly appreciated. Thanks

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using SAPFEWSELib;
using SapROTWr;
using AVTAR.SAPLibrary;
using AVTAR.CustomLibrary;

namespace AvatarTest1 {
   public class Sap {
   public static GuiApplication SapGuiApp { get; set; }
   public static GuiConnection SapConnection { get; set; }
   public static GuiSession SapSession { get; set; }
   
public static void openSap(string env) {
       Sap.SapGuiApp = new GuiApplication();

       string connectString = null;
       if (env.ToUpper().Equals("DEFAULT")) {
        connectString = "1.0 Test ERP (DEFAULT)";
        //connectString = "ASHOST = n7p.naan.as.com SYSNR = N7P 
 CLIENT = 
 460 _USER = ***** PASSWD = ****";*******";
       } else {
        connectString = env;
       }
       Sap.SapConnection = Sap.SapGuiApp.OpenConnection(connectString, 
 Sync: true); //creates connection
       //Sap.SapSession = (GuiSession)Sap.SapConnection.Sessions.Item(0); 
//creates the Gui session off the connection you made
   }

   public void Login(string userId,string pass,string clientid) {
       try {
           for (int i = 0; i <= 50; i++) {
                Sap.SapSession = SapGuiApp.ActiveSession;
           }
           // System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program 
 Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe");

            GuiTextField Clientfield = 
 (GuiTextField)SapSession.ActiveWindow.FindById("wnd[0] / usr / txtRSYST - 
 MANDT");
            GuiTextField UserIDField = 
(GuiTextField)SapSession.ActiveWindow.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME");
            GuiTextField PassField = 
(GuiTextField)SapSession.ActiveWindow.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/pwdRSYST-BCODE");
            //GuiTextField LanguageField = 
(GuiTextField)SapSession.ActiveWindow.FindById("wnd[0]/usr/txtRSYST-BNAME");
            Clientfield.SetFocus();
            Clientfield.Text = clientid;
            UserIDField.SetFocus();
            UserIDField.Text = userId;
            PassField.SetFocus();
            PassField.Text = pass;
            //Sap.SapSession ssn= new  SapSession.FindById("wnd[0]")
            GuiButton enter = 
(GuiButton)SapSession.ActiveWindow.FindById("wnd[0]");
            enter.Press();
        }
    catch (Exception ex)
        {

            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
        }
}
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

In your Code you commented out "System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(@"C:\Program 
 Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\saplogon.exe");"

Go with this aproach, but use "sapshcut.exe" from the same Folder instead!
(this will be available on the most systems)

In this case it could be as simple as that:

```
string strProg="C:\Program Files\SAP\FrontEnd\SAPgui\sapshcut.exe";
string strParam="-system=N7P -client=460 -user=youruser -password=yourpassword -language=EN";
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start(strProg,strParam);
```

Find an (VBA)Examle with some pre-Tests on the Commanline at [trouble using excel macro for access to sap](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47143866/trouble-using-excel-macro-for-access-to-sap/47296481#47296481)

Hope this will do ist for you!

Comment: Lemme try with dis as well. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Thanks now i am able to log in directly. The problem is earlier i could enter the value in transaction code fields, but now i am unable. will try to solve that. The best thing is it don't show error for multiple logon through your code